# Project structure for C# project with VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So I'm experienced with Java and C/C++ for some years now and I'm trying do dive into C# right now. My primary problem right now is that I dont know how to get a good PRoject structure with Microsofts Visual Studio going.

From Java with Eclipse I'm used to something like

```
[root]
|- bin
|  |- //here go the class files of the IDE
|- build
|  |- bin
|     |- //build class files from ant script or whatever
|  |- //... other build resources like jar files
|- src
|  |- //here com the actual source code in it's package structure
|- //other resources like build.xml
```

Now with VS a project usually is put inside a Projectfolder and go with many other files that seem like to be important for VS yet i dont see a satisfying project structure there.

I've been reading through a book as well as a bit through the Internet but haven't find a fitting answer for my question:
How am I able to achive something like the given structure above within VS? Or what is the convention to use in a C# Project? What is some good/bad practice in that terms?

Appreciate any advice!

Comment: On a related StackExchange fora: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/369504/directory-structure-for-a-net-solution . For example this one from David Fowler: 
https://gist.github.com/davidfowl/ed7564297c61fe9ab814

Comment: Eclipse has taught you some bad habits.  VS treats the build artifacts as irrelevant and something you never have to worry about.  At the root is the *solution*, below it are the projects that produce the final program.  The Solution Explorer window gives you the primary view, it is focused on showing your code and hides all the noise.  You can click its "Show All Files" toolbar button to reveal the noise, there is very rarely a good reason to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the following repository of [Equinox Project](https://github.com/EduardoPires/EquinoxProject).
It is posed as showcase of implementing popular .NET technologies in one project. You could find their project structure useful.